# How do I pass an environment variable to the application.conf using the Datastax Java Cassandra Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, hocon

I have the current `application.conf`...

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.contact-points = ["192.168.23.1:9042"]
  basic {
    load-balancing-policy {
      local-datacenter = datacenter1
    }
  }
  advanced.metrics {
    factory.class = MicrometerMetricsFactory
  }
  advanced.request.warn-if-set-keyspace = false
  advanced.auth-provider {
    class = PlainTextAuthProvider
    username = cassandra
    password = cassandra
  }
  profiles {
    slow {
      basic.request.timeout = 10 seconds
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a env var with the IP address DOCKER_IP. I tried

`basic.contact-points = ["${DOCKER_IP}:9042"]`

But it didn't work and instead defaulted to the local computer.

Comment: Sounds like it worked fine, just didn't evaluate to the value you expected. I.e, it didn't remain a literal as `${DOCKER_IP}:9042`

Comment: Not sure I follow if I hard code it works but if I try to use the env var it resorts to the default because it can't find it (or can't parse it because the Env var is not resolving) What I need is the correct voodoo to get it to resolve and pass the env var properly

Comment: Well, 1) the file appears to be HOCON config - https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/main/HOCON.md#substitution-fallback-to-environment-variables 2) The seed addresses and listeners from Cassandra matter as well - https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/configuring.html 3) If you run Cassandra within Docker container with a port-forward, you don't need an IP address, anyway

Comment: We aren't/can't use port-forward so we need it to be an external IP I can try to look into number 2 thank you for the idea

Comment: Not sure I understand "can't"? Port forwarding from Docker Desktop hypervisor will be required if not running the container on Linux.

Comment: @OneCricketeer in other words I am limited on what I can do so if that is setup wrong it would be an admin fix since I don't have permissions

Answer (score 2):

The answer offered by [@Madhavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10410162/madhavan) above is absolutely correct.  For sake of completeness I wanted to expand on it just a bit.

The Java driver uses the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) lib to perform it's configuration.  That lib provides a couple different methods for overriding config values at runtime.  Out of the box you can override any config value by providing a system property that exactly matches the config name.  So to override the specified contact points you could use the following flag when invoking the JVM:

```
-Ddatastax-java-driver.basic.contact-points.1='1.2.3.4:9042'
```

The ".1" suffix is added here because "contact-points" is an array of values; see [the docs](https://github.com/lightbend/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides) for more detail.

The second option is to enable environment variable overrides for config values and then provide the appropriate env var.  To enable this feature you should provide the following system property:

```
-Dconfig.override_with_env_vars=true
```

You can then provide the value for any config variable via an environment variable.  For example, to accomplish the same replacement specified above you might use the following env var:

```
CONFIG_FORCE_datastax__java__driver_basic_contact__points_0="1.2.3.4:9042"
```

You can find additional information about the "CONFIG_FORCE_" prefix and the rules around translating config property names into environment variables in the Typesafe Config docs referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

[@clunven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890779/clunven) suggested that it is possible and [here is an example](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactive/blob/master/src/main/resources/application-local.conf) where it is done.

TL;DR

set it as `contact-points = [${CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS}]` and the env variable is set as `CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS: "cassandra:9042"` as an example.

Comment: This did not work